# How can I build ejabberd source code in eclipse

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlide

I want to build ejabberd source code in eclipse. I follow these steps for this.

```
1. Download ejabberd source code from git hub from this link

 https://github.com/processone/ejabberd.

2. Add erlide plugin in eclipse.

3. Now i import it as general project in elipse.

**source code import successfully. But it shows error** 

     Error:

     *record xmlel undefined*
```

Can anyone knows how we can import ejabberd source code in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ejabberd download all the dependencies, has defined in `rebar.config.script` or `mix.exs`.

You need a lot of subcomponents. It seems for example you are missing ProcessOne XML module which defines de `xmlel` record: https://github.com/processone/xml

Typically, to build ejabberd from source, you need to:

- Generate the configure: `./autogen.sh`
- Run configure with the module you need: `./configure`
- run `make`

You need to instruct Eclipse of these steps to build ejabberd.
ejabberd documentation explains how to build ejabberd from source: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-from-source-code

Note that if you have on Windows, you may need to find a way to build the native C Erlang module (Like XML, TLS, Zlib, etc).

As a sidenote, ejabberd development is made on Emacs, which is probably the reference tool to development in Erlang in general.